# Accessing and binding events to an ASP.NET Grid view using Jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have an ASP page which displays a text box when it loads. It takes an input number, send it to the server through post back, and then displays some record in a grid view. After a number is input into the box, the server fetches some data from a database and add records to the grid view. It also contains a link column, whose URL is set to "#", so that the page isn't redirected when it is clicked.

Now I want to bind a jquery "click" event to that link. How can I do that ? I have tried that to do myself but failed, because it is not available when the DOM is loaded (since it only contains rows when a number is input through the box), and is being modified through ASP.NET Ajax post back.

Comment: Why binding the click event with jquery if you can easily set the onclick event of the link when you build your grid?

Comment: @Joop: He's probably using a HyperLinkColumn.

Comment: Yes, I am using a HyperLinkColumn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use the [live](http://api.jquery.com/live) handlers in jQuery to do this.  I'd give these links a specific class to uniquely identify them and make it easier.

```
 $('a.gridLink').live('click', function() {
     ... perform your action...
     return false; // to cancel the default click action
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

i think you're looking for [.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function:

```
$('#<%=myGrid.ClientID%> a').live("click", function(e) {
    //Do things
    return false;  //You don't need to set the href to #
});
```